# Why should I hatch Tallbird eggs?

Tags: dont-starve

From what I know, newborn Tallbirds are very weak, get hungry all the time and follow player everywhere, making it hard to keep them alive. And after they grow into adult Tallbirds, they become hostile towards player. It also doesn't seem like they will create a nest to spawn eggs in, so it seems kind of useless and effortsome to hatch the eggs at the cost of a nice dinner. If killed, a Tallbird drops 2 meats, and while a normal Tallbird will respawn in 2.5 days, it takes a lot more to grow one from an egg.

In comparison, pigs have 250 HP and do 33 dmg, don't need food (unless you want them to follow you around). Smallish Tallbirds have 300 HP and do 50 dmg, but they require 60 food per day, each, which can be a nuisance. Pigs are better for this follower role, because they're ready to fight right off the bat, no need to wait 11 days.

Why would I want to spend so much time and resources to hatch a Tallbird egg?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet.  Can they at least serve as useful NPCs who help in battles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only real advantage of the smallbird and smallish tallbird is that some mobs don't run away from them.  Birds like crows, redbirds, etc. won't fly away from them, so the smallbird can be an easy source of feathers and morsels.

I guess you could also herd them into a pen, and have your own tallbird farm.

So, to answer your question:  as near as I can tell, the value is fairly limited.

Answer (score 1):

I find that the newborn tallbird is actually quite useful, not to mention cute. (But that's my opinion) But the way the newborn is useful is that it's very good at hunting the crows and Redbirds, along with the turkeys. (I don't remember their exact name) I also like to chase away baby beefalo from their parents, and then set the baby tallbird on it, also hunting it myself. I don't know about the smallish tallbird, my baby tallbird died before it became a smallish tallbird. (Rest in spaghetti, never forgetti)

But my main point is that the baby tallbird isn't that useless. You get a great supply of food (morsels from birds or drumsticks from turkeys)and feathers, until it either dies or becomes a smallish tallbird.