# How do I hatch a Tallbird egg?

Tags: dont-starve

So I've managed to survive the onslaught of Tallbirds and get a few Tallbird eggs. How do I hatch them? And what are they useful for (other than pecking you to death when they grow up)?

Comment: Better off utilizing them in crockpot recipes for food that provide a lot of health and hunger.

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [Don't Starve wikia](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Tallbird_Egg),

> A Tallbird Egg can also be placed near a fire, where it will become a Hatching Tallbird Egg and eventually hatch into a Smallbird.
>
> A Hatching Tallbird Egg is a Tallbird Egg that has started to hatch after being placed near a Campfire or Fire Pit for at least 10 seconds. Hatching takes roughly 3 days before it will become a Smallbird.

And concerning the second part of your enquiry, a [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152174/why-should-i-hatch-tallbird-eggs) has already been answered on the stackexchange.